# Mongoose & MongoDB: ignore cast errors when performing a bulkWrite

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, error-handling

I'm trying to import data into my app's database using the bulkWrite operation supported in MongoDB. Since it comes from an external source, there might be errors in the data. That's why I want to update my collection while skipping documents not meeting the criteria to maintain the integrity of my own data. However, I get a cast error if the data is not clean and the update is blocked whenever I try to run my code. One might argue that the data must be cleaned beforehand, which I agree, but I want to make sure my update won't crash when an error is overlooked. The following sample code makes it clear and replicates the type of error I'm trying to avoid:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

data = [
  {
    description: "nice product",
    stock: 10,
    product_id: "01"
  },
  {
    description: "useful product",
    stock: "error will be generated",
    product_id: "02"
  }
];

const InventorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  description: String,
  stock: Number,
  product_id: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  }
});
const Inventory = mongoose.model("Inventory", InventorySchema);

const upsertData = () => {
  Inventory.bulkWrite(data.map((product) => {
    return ({ updateOne: {
      filter: { product_id: product.product_id },
      update: { $set: product },
      upsert: true
    }});
  })).catch(e => {console.log(e);});
}

mongoose.connection.once("open", () => {
  upsertData();
});
```

This sample code will generate the following error: ***CastError: Cast to Number failed for value "error will be generated" at path "stock"***. Ideally, when importing a long inventory of products, the program should try to update or create each document without crashing everytime it loops through invalid data.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve the issue directly, so I decided to take a different approach: instead of performing a bulkWrite, I looped through the data array and divided the operation in two parts for each product. 1) check if a product exists with the same ID, and 2) update the collection or create a new document depending on the first condition. However, this approach is not as operationally efficient as a bulkWrite. In any case, I decided to share my solution in case others find it useful. Let me know what you think!

```
const upsertData = () => {
  data.map(async (product) => {
    let exists = await Inventory.findOne({ product_id: product.product_id });
    if (exists) {
      // Update document if product exists
      Inventory.updateOne({ product_id: product.product_id }, product)
        .catch((e) => { console.log(e); });
    } else {
      // Create if product does not exist or ignore if data is unclean
      Inventory.create(product).catch((e) => {return});
    }
  });
}
```